# How to add a "default address" option to the new address form on the Magento 2 checkout page?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I want to add a "default address" option to the new address form on the Magento 2 checkout page. If selected, I want the added address to be the default billing and shipping address after it is saved.

[image]